# Understanding promises a little more

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, sequelize.js

I'm struggling to make this works. i'm dealing with sequelize promisses and i want to return the queried elements to the view, but instead its returning null. I know its because promises are async requests and it does not return a result immediatly after you call it, ok, but how to return the values, put it into an array and than return the array?

this is the code i have so far.

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
var sales = req.body.sales;
var person = req.body.personID;
var promisses = [];
var delivery = req.body.delivery;
for(var i =0;i<sales.length;i++){
    var product_id = sales[i].product_id;
    var amount = sales[i].amount;
    var price = sales[i].produto_price;

    var salePromisse = Sale.create({
      'product_id': product_id,
      'person_id': person,
      'amount': amount,
      'price': price,
      'total': amount*price
    });
    //i couldnt find a word which describes what movimentacao means...lets keep it.
    var movimentacao = Movimentacao.create({
      "tipo": 0,
      "id_product": product_id,
      "id_provider": "",
      "data": new Date(),
      "price": amount*price
    });
    promisses.push(salePromisse);
    promisses.push(movimentacPromisse);
}


Promise.all(promisses).then(function (promissesArray){
var name = "";
var suc = 0;
var total = 0;
var salesResult = [];
var salesObject = {};
if(!delivery){
  res.send({msg: "aaaaa"});
}else{
  promissesArray.forEach(function(pro){
    if(pro!==null && pro !== undefined){
      if(pro['$modelOptions'].tableName === undefined){
        Product.findById(pro.product_id).then(function (product){
          salesObject.product = product.name;
          salesObject.price= pro.price;
          salesObject.amount = pro.amount;
          salesObject.total = pro.total;
          total += salesObject.total;
          salesResult.push(salesObject);
          salesObject = {};
          return Person.findById(per);
        }).then(function (person) {
           name = person.name;
        });;
      }
    }        
  });
  //here is where i would like to return to the view salesResult and name.
  //res.render("folder/view", {sales: salesResult, person: name});
  console.log(salesResult);
}

});
```

});

Well, the promisses array has the CREATE instance for each of my models, and i'm creating a few types of it.
I want to insert on the database, check if the promise resolved is dealing with an specific table (the field modelOptions is undefined on it, i already debugged), query all the other results because on the promisses array i have just the id, and than put into the array to be able to return to the view, but on the console.log on the last line, it returns null. How can i improve the code to be able to do all i want and than return to the view?

Dont worry, all the model related variables are beeing declared above.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to know about `Promise.all` already. What were you using it for, do you understand what it does?

Comment: You probably need to show us how you're trying to use the result for the view because you CANNOT return a simple array from the code you have above.  You can return a promise that will fulfill to an array, but then the calling code has to use that returned promise.  So, please show a larger context of your code so we can offer a full solution.

Comment: @Bergi im using to resolve all the promises i did above, its just a few create sequelize instances.

Comment: @jfriend00 more code added. I'm having problems to understand how to fill the array inside the promise, thats the point. the console.log is just a mockup for where i will call the view, but its added anyways. This is the workflow: `form-submit->controller->insert->foreachInserted(it has ids, so i have to query names)->fillArray->send-to-view.`

Comment: @MatheusSilva: The point is that you should not fill an array from inside promise callbacks. Instead, you should fill an array *of promises*, and then use `Promise.all` on that.

Comment: @Bergi So the best way to return results based on multiple promises is to fill the array and resolve like that? Well, if i want to create a new object from the resolved array, like what i do above, will am i be able to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, just put a `.then()` handler on the `Promise.all` and build the object from the array elements

Comment: In the provided code example `console.log(salesResult);` gets executed prematurely because `salesResult` is not ready yet. If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you should have that code inside the last `.then()` handler (where you read person's name).